# Can't run javaFX/Spring Boot application from Jar : Location is not set

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, javafx, jar

I have been working on an application with JavaFX and spring boot, it workes fine when I launch it from the Eclipse IDE but if I run the generated jar using :
java -jar AppXX.jar it gives me the error below:

```
    Exception in Application init method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/Users/XX/target/MDV2.0-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/X/anotherProject/view/Welcome.fxml

        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.X.anotherProject.AnotherProjectApplication.init(AnotherProjectApplication.java:42)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.X.anotherProject.Controller.WelcomeController.FireAnEvent(WelcomeController.java:464)
        at com.X.anotherProject.Controller.WelcomeController.initialize(WelcomeController.java:338)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/Users/XX/target/MDV2.0-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/X/anotherProject/view/Kits%20de%20migration.fxml

        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.sopraMdv.anotherProject.Controller.WelcomeController.loadInMainPane(WelcomeController.java:453)
        at com.X.anotherProject.Controller.WelcomeController.press(WelcomeController.java:398)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.X.anotherProject.Controller.WelcomeController.loadInMainPane(WelcomeController.java:453)
        at com.X.anotherProject.Controller.KitListController.AddElemnt(KitListController.java:115)
        at com.X.anotherProject.Controller.KitListController.initialize(KitListController.java:98)
        ... 56 more
```

this is how I load the FXML file in my class :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }



    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {

        springContext = SpringApplication.run(AnotherProjectApplication.class);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader= new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/X/anotherProject/view/Welcome.fxml"));
        springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(AnotherProjectApplication.springContext::getBean);
        rootNode=fxmlLoader.load();
    }
```

note that I have checked a lot of related problems and none of them worked.
The thing is that `getClass().getResource()` cannot find the FXML file. 
When I opened the jar with Winrar I found the file in the given path :

file:/C:/Users/XX/target/MDV2.0-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/X/anotherProject/view/Welcome.fxml

[image]

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like it actually does find your `Welcome.fxml` file, as well as a second FXML file, but then fails on a third. Do you have nested FXML files (i.e. `fx:include`)?

Comment: [Similar questions, regarding "location not set"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javafx+location+not+set+fxml) have been asked numerous times on StackOverflow, is the answer to your question in any of the answers there?

Comment: Thanks @Slaw, in fact I have nested FXML files and after I checked all the FXML files I found that some files had an error in spelling like for instance, the file name was "Kit.fxml" with capital K and I put "kit.fxml" in the code. But the thing is, Eclipse IDE didn't have a problem with this difference in letters but when I run the jar file it raises the error.

Comment: I have fixed the spelling errors and it all works fine now, Thanks for your help.

Comment: When running your application from an IDE your code is not packaged in a JAR file. This means the application is using the file system of the underlying OS which may or may not be case-sensitive. For instance, Windows typically has a case-insensitive file system. Once packaged in a JAR file, however, the "file system" is _always_ case-sensitive. In short, make sure you use the exact spelling and capitalization when referencing resources.

Comment: (sorry for the repeat comment, was having issues on my end)